# Wrapping elements while looping through HTMLCollection causes problem

Tags: javascript, html, loops, htmlcollection

I want to wrap each item of the container in a div. When I loop through HTMLCollection, some elements are accessed multiple times while others are left out

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item_1"></div>
    <div class="item_2"></div>
    <div class="item_3"></div>
    <div class="item_4"></div>
    <div class="item_5"></div>
    <div class="item_6"></div>
    <div class="item_7"></div>
    <div class="item_8"></div>
    <div class="item_9"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const items = container.children;

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
    wrapper.appendChild(items[i]);
    container.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

Looping directly through HTMLCollection gives this bizarre result

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="item_2"></div>
        <div class="item_4"></div>
        <div class="item_6"></div>
        <div class="item_8"></div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="item_1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="item_5"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="item_9"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="item_7"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="item_3"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

problem gets solved when I convert HTMLCollection to an Array

```
const items = Array.from(container.children);
```

I can't understand what causes such behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were iterating the `container.children` list which you were also changing during the iterations. This messed up the iteration. You can solve this, as you mentioned yourself, by converting the `container.children` to an array because then you are not iterating over the live `container.children` list but over an array copy of that. This copy is still referring to the correct child elements so they are moved correctly with the `appendChild()` function.

As an alternative you can use the `querySelecterAll()` to retrieve all the elements you want to wrap.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const items = container.querySelectorAll('.container > *');

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
    wrapper.appendChild(items[i]);
    container.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item_1">1</div>
    <div class="item_2">2</div>
    <div class="item_3">3</div>
    <div class="item_4">4</div>
    <div class="item_5">5</div>
    <div class="item_6">6</div>
    <div class="item_7">7</div>
    <div class="item_8">8</div>
    <div class="item_9">9</div>
</div>
```